# WP Rest API: new route return rest_invalid_handler

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

This is a simple test script for create a new route:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'ass', '/ativar', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'testing_route',
  ) );
} );

function testing_route($data){
    return array( 'message' => 'testing route' );
}
```

But it returning an error message:

> rest_invalid_handler

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved!

```
'callback' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\\testing_route',
```

Comment: Edit this so it becomes the answer of your question

Comment: nice, forgot to concatenate the namespace :)

Comment: Also note, if you are using a object method as a callback, it needs to have public visibility, else it will return nothing.

Answer (score 13):

In my case I was setting up `register_rest_route` within a function inside of my class. I simply added:

```php
'callback' => array($this, 'name_of_callback_function'),
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
'callback' => __CLASS__ . '::testing_route',
```

Comment: You should specif an answer more extends and with more details

Comment: Solved my issue when using class methods vs instance methods.  Ripper!

Answer (score 1):

Your callback shouldn't take any args, just remove `$data`

Comment: actually, the callbacks need this argument in case they have to do anything with the data sent in the requests